# How to unset statistics of a raster using gdal_edit.py

Tags: python, raster, gdal, cell-statistics

I would like to use gdal_edit.py to unset the statistics associated with some tifs. I'm using python to do so, but it's not working for me. I get a 0 exit code but a message saying "Unexpected option C:\Users\NAME\EnvData\temp.tif" comes up and the code doesn't actually do anything.
How do I point gdal_edit.py towards the input tif? and better yet an output file too.

Here is my code:

```
import subprocess as sp
import sys

gdaledit = r"C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts\gdal_edit.py"

data = r"C:\Users\NAME\EnvData\temp.tif"

sp.call([sys.executable, gdaledit, '-unsetstats', data])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fundamentally the failure of [subprocess.call](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) is a python issue and not a GDAL issue. I personally use [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) because I can create a list of process objects each with their own [stdout and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr) pipes so I can read about any processes that have failed, both the normal and error messages, and then have multiple processes active at one time... but all of that is off-topic for GIS.SE.

GDAL_Edit is a python script itself so it's not to hard to see what it's trying to do, though it would be daunting for a newbie to either GDAL or python. The pertinent lines condense down to:

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import osr
data = r"C:\Users\NAME\EnvData\temp.tif"      # using your data path
ds   = gdal.Open(datasetname, gdal.GA_Update) # open the raster for update

for i in range(ds.RasterCount):               # Loop through the bands
    band = ds.GetRasterBand(i+1)
    for key in band.GetMetadata().keys():     # get the metadata for this band and iterate the keys
        if key.startswith('STATISTICS_'):     # if this key is STATISTICS...
            band.SetMetadataItem(key, None)   # set this key to None
```

As for the output raster, there is none, this tool edits the target raster in place; it's quicker but you've got no defacto backup so make sure you keep a copy/zip of the file if it's important.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!